# How do I set the Foot IK property of an animator state by code?

Tags: unity, animation, inverse-kinematics

I would like to set Foot IK to enabled via code, but I can't find how.

Which type is "Foot IK" a part of?

[image: Screenshot of animator state inspector showing Foot IK checkbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want [AnimatorState.iKOnFeet](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorState-iKOnFeet.html).

You can navigate to an `AnimatorState` from an `AnimatorController` by...

1. Using [AnimatorContoller.layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController-layers.html) to navigate the layers in the control graph.
2. Using [AnimatorControllerLayer.stateMachine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorControllerLayer-stateMachine.html) to access the state machine for the selected layer.
3. Using [AnimatorStateMachine.states](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorStateMachine-states.html) to navigate the states present in this state machine.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that it's actually so labour-intensive, but when I looked at it, it became obvious. Thank you.